# PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x13f305e90> give this error in django and image path retrive from s3 is

Tags: django, amazon-s3

When I open Image url given by django it gives this.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAR4APO3UQB6EPRHZK</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20231208T141342Z 20231208/eu-north-1/s3/aws4_request 7c1cadaceeabd5fd2551d7de369db9c9b1fdd0741e5077490b8b3f8599a157b4</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>b9a5a710e118bb6fb3f7d442191a8a5be293fa8a3838465e466063c4b9214635</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 33 31 32 30 38 54 31 34 31 33 34 32 5a 0a 32 30 32 33 31 32 30 38 2f 65 75 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 37 63 31 63 61 64 61 63 65 65 61 62 64 35 66 64 32 35 35 31 64 37 64 65 33 36 39 64 62 39 63 39 62 31 66 64 64 30 37 34 31 65 35 30 37 37 34 39 30 62 38 62 33 66 38 35 39 39 61 31 35 37 62 34</StringToSignBytes>
<CanonicalRequest>GET /media/images/pexels-jonas-f-13020734.jpg X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAR4APO3UQB6EPRHZK%2F20231208%2Feu-north-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231208T141342Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host host:captiongenerator.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com host UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest>
<CanonicalRequestBytes>47 45 54 0a 2f 6d 65 64 69 61 2f 69 6d 61 67 65 73 2f 70 65 78 65 6c 73 2d 6a 6f 6e 61 73 2d 66 2d 31 33 30 32 30 37 33 34 2e 6a 70 67 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 52 34 41 50 4f 33 55 51 42 36 45 50 52 48 5a 4b 25 32 46 32 30 32 33 31 32 30 38 25 32 46 65 75 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 2d 31 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 32 33 31 32 30 38 54 31 34 31 33 34 32 5a 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 33 36 30 30 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 53 69 67 6e 65 64 48 65 61 64 65 72 73 3d 68 6f 73 74 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 63 61 70 74 69 6f 6e 67 65 6e 65 72 61 74 6f 72 2e 73 33 2e 65 75 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 2d 31 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes>
<RequestId>KX3SQ4RTXEVAWYAX</RequestId>
<HostId>LqKINgPs8nHSQieAqWbwRwK85cevc5WbpEdGk2TZA7nlQh27toMOhc3/5G3uJjSK6twdMvkBST8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I think image url retrived  from AWS S3 bucket is wrong.

I make AWS S3 Bucket public but it not worked for me.